# Changes is Default CSS value

Tags: sharepoint-online

If I change in sharepoint online the default CSS values in a View, for example, is there any risk of a breaking change when microsoft updates the platform?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cross posting to get more attention isn't good.

Comment: It won't break, it might not be applied if Microsoft changes something. You could automate testing if webpages are the way you want them... but that is going to cost you, and not really wortwhile unless you have over a million users or so. The nature of the Cloud Beast is we (including end-users) have to be able to adopt to changes.

Comment: @Uniforms For Sale, understood! I apologise for that.

Answer (score 1):

With SharePoint online, their is always risk. Because as per their agreement, MSFT install update without letting anybody know. So one morning you noticed that your customization broke.

I am little doubted about the CSS overwriting, i never experienced that so far.

Check this link, it will help you to do some troubleshooting.

[Supporting Office 365 Customisations](http://omicron-llama.com/2014/01/29/supporting-office365-customisations/)